# Passing a ref to a collection element

Tags: c#, struct, reference

I am building an application that communicates with a box using a .dll. Consider the box as a black box, all you need to know is that I can access the box's memory using the dll functions and references.

Now, my application need to have a dictionary (I consider replacing with array if needed) that will contain structs which located in the box's memory. I need to pass a struct from the collection to the box using a ref, and the box then will update the struct's data. The problem is that I can't pass an entry from the collection as a ref directly, because its a dynamic member.

I thought about passing an element from the collection as a local member that will be passed as a ref and after the box updates, I will update myself the structs as needed, but I rather passing a ref to the structs directlt.

How do I pass a ref to an element in a collectiin directly?

Comment: Perhaps use a class instead.

Comment: Its not my decision, the dll implemened those structs.

Comment: @Matan A class containing a single field. That single field has the DLL's struct as its type.

Comment: The dll function gets a ref to a struct thats is my problem

Comment: I would create a collection of elements that have a member field containing that struct. Then you can pass a reference to that member. But note that passing persistent references to managed .NET memory isn't a particularly good idea in the first place. You might need to lock the memory anyway which means more housekeeping.

Comment: A reference to the "black box'" memory is a *pointer*.  C# supports them well, both as IntPtr and a typed managed pointer.  The odds that you think about this problem correctly are small, already visible in having the pointer the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about a solution myself.. My solution is to use an array of structs instead of a Dictionary.. I have lost some functionality but it's something I can live with. I can write myself functions that will give me the functions I want from a dictionary.

Something like this:

```
MessageStruct[] messages = new MessageStruct[64];

messages[0] = new MessageStruct();

UpdateMessage(ref messages[0]);

Console.writeline(message[0]);
```

Another solution is what Lasse V. Karlsen offered..

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `ref`, just pass your `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` normally, since it is a reference type itself any modification made by your box will be reflected in your dictionary afterwards!

e.g.

```
myBox.DoStuffWith(myDictionary);
// changes to a particular value in dictionary will be accessible, e.g.
Console.WriteLine(((StructType)myDictionary[myKey].Value).Member);
```

*UPDATE:*

Following you comment:

> the function look like this: UpdateMessage(ref message)

You could to this:

```
Message msg = myDictionary[id];
UpdateMessage(ref msg);
myDictionary[id] = msg
```

*UPDATE2:*

You said you want to avoid this. [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) are designed for when you have no control over the Type (the one in the DLL with Update() on it, lets call it MessageUpdater), so you could wrap the above in one:

```
class MessageExtensions
{
    public static Message Update(this MessageUpdater updater, Dictionary<int,Message> dict, int key)
    {
        Message value = dict[key];
        MessageUpdater.Update(ref value);
        return dict[key];
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
Message updatedMessage = myMessageUpdater.Update(myDict, key);
```

Is that acceptable?

Comment: This requires cooperation with the external DLL. If the external DLL doesn't support this, the main program's code cannot be modified to work around that fact.

Comment: is the external DLL a CLR one? (You need to show us some code, otherwise we are just guessing).

Comment: (To make it clear, it's not my question.) The answer doesn't depend on how the external DLL is implemented, it depends on what functions that DLL exports. And the question already includes enough details for a workable answer regardless of the DLL: my comment on the question should work for any DLL. The only question is whether there's a better answer than that.

Comment: Yup and if the DLL has a function accepting a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey,TValue> it would have modified the values and you will see them afterwards

Comment: No the function look like this: UpdateMessage(ref message) and the message is a struct, and I cant paas the element directly from the dictiinary it doesn't works like that.

Comment: Updated my answer again! It would have been easier had you included what the code looked like to begin with :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining a simple class:

```
public class ExposedFieldHolder<T>
{
  public T Value;
  public ExposedFieldHolder(T val) { Value = val; }
}
```

and then using a `Dictionary<TKey, ExposedFieldHolder<MessageStruct>>`.  When adding something to the dictionary, you'll have to create a `new ExposedFieldHolder<MessageStruct>` holding the appropriate value, but to modify something in the dictionary you'll be able to:

```
UpdateMessage(ref theDictionary[theKey].Value);
```

and have the update happen in-place.  Note that this technique can also allow the use of things like `Interlocked.CompareExchange` with primitives like `Int32` stored in wrappers in a dictionary.